# How do aerodynamics for small model aircraft differ from that of larger aircraft?

Tags: fixed-wing, aerodynamics

I am reading an aerodynamics textbook (Introduction to Aerodynamics by Anderson). I am still in the chapters that deal with subsonic aerodynamics, which seems to have a focus on life-sized manned aircraft. I am wondering: are there major differences in the consideration of aerodynamics when designing model aircraft as opposed to life-sized manned aircraft?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/do-aerodynamics-scale-for-model-aircraft

Answer (score 5):

The largest difference is that in [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), which is the same issue that wind tunnel models have. The Reynolds number is linear in length, which for the wing is the chord length. So for example, a quarter-scale model will have a Reynolds number equal to one-forth that of the full-scale aircraft (in the same atmospheric conditions). The reason this matters is that airflow tends to transition from laminar to turbulent at a specific Reynolds number, so if one uses the same airfoil on the model as in the full-scale aircraft, then usually the performance will be different near stall (usually much worse). That is why reduced-scale models usually change to an airfoil that is designed for lower Reynolds numbers.

BTW, Intro to Aerodynamics by Anderson is excellent. That was my first textbook when I started aero engineering over 30 years ago.